# Should I return a pointer to beginning of an array or particular element?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I frequently run into a situation where I have an array member variable and external functions need to access its elements. Let's take as an example the following code:

```
class example_t
{
   protected:
      int* array;
      size_t size;  

   public:
      example_t(size_t size = 100) : size(size)
      {
         array = new[size];

         // .. fill the array ..
      }

      ~example_t()
      {
         delete[] array;
      }

      size_t get_size(void) const { return size; }   
      int const * get_array(void) const { return array; }
      int get_array_element(size_t n) const { return array[n]; }
};
```

**Which interface should be the preferred method of accessing the array**, `get_array()[n]` or `get_array_element(n)`? I am trying to consider here both the style and possibility of having duplicate calls eliminated by the optimizer, for example if `array` stores some indices in a different array and we wish to compute

```
example_t subset(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < subset.get_size(); i++)
{
   result[subset.get_array_element(i)] = f(input[subset.get_array_element(i)]);
}
```

then one would hope for the repeated calls to be eliminated by the compiler. **Would the choice of interface have any influence on the possible optimizations**?

*Note: I am aware that I could have used `std::vector<int> array`, this is just an example.*

Comment: Have you considered overloading the `operator []`?

Comment: [Both are incredibly bad](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), but exposing everything wholesale is definitely worse than selectively exposing elements.

Comment: @PeterT: this is a simplified example; usually the `operator[]` would not be natural and thus I would not overload it.

Comment: You could consider the [Iterator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

Comment: this is not 'C' so suggest removing the 'C' tag

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on what your code is supposed to do, and likely has no effect on optimisations at all. Either your class loads the pointer and dereferences it, or your call site does. Either way if you're doing it within the loop the result is exactly the same. You should measure it to be sure but I'd be surprised to see any difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, probably you would use operator[] instead of get_array_element(n), but those are just different syntaxes and should be the same from a performance standpoint.

I think the biggest influence will be whether or not the compile can inline these functions. That depends on their size (right now they're tiny, so yes), the optimization level you compile at, and where the class lives. If it's in a header file, or in the same file as the code that uses it, then yes.

But if the methods are defined in a separate C++ file that's compiled to a separate module, then the compiler won't be able to inline the functions calls most likely. In that case, having to call a method to get each element will matter.

Also if you make the methods virtual and access a subclass through a base class pointer, that would also defeat inlining.

If you want to do any sort of sanity check on the indexes, then returning a pointer to the array is out of the question.

I would go so far as to say, if you're going to have a function that returns a pointer to the array, you might as well just make the array itself public. It's hard to imagine any benefit an accessor method would have in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to come up with a standard approach for many such classes, bear in mind that returning a pointer instead of a copy *might* be faster for vectors of non-POD data (a class with a copy constructor for example).

On the other hand, a standard already exists, in the form of the const and non const [] operators, and I'd be inclined to mimic those even if using them directly wasn't appropriate.

Comment: for non-POD data you would rather pass a reference (or const reference) rather then making a copy

Comment: If it were non-POD I would indeed return a reference; assume it is POD or even simpler, just a standard type. I mostly run into this when I have an array of `int`.

Comment: I have found in the pass that passing a vector of 2 or 3 floats by copy is sometimes faster than passing it by reference or pointer.  Why this should be so is not clear to me - perhaps it is sometimes easier for compilers to optimize, or it plays more nicely with the cache when used afterwards.  I think copy is definitely easier to read - no thinking required.